# Alert dialog with items that can be searched - Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog with the following:

- setitems that adds a dynamic array of string
- setView that adds an edit text that searches the string of array (it's irrelevant how the search is being done)
- in the edittext added I have a addTextChangedListener attached to it which should reset the items in the alertdialog without it being recreated

this is whole code:

```
        builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    items = new  CharSequence[10]; 
    //here  I am setting the items

    builder.setTitle(“TITLE”)
    .setItems(items , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            //doing something here              
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

    EditText searchEditText=new EditText(this);         
    myAlertDialog=builder.setView(searchEditText).create();

    searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            CharSequence[] items2 = new  CharSequence[20]; 
            //here i am setting the new items

            builder.setItems(items2 , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    //doing something meaningless here
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

nothing happens when I do this. I first tried using a spinner but I can't add an edittext with a spinner.

thank you,

**---EDIT--**
here's an image of how it looks like.

[image]